# How to get a ranking result for special record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following query

```
SELECT id, name from `users` ORDER BY points desc LIMIT $n*$row,$row
```

that will select part of my user tables and then I will show them. ranking of these users calculate as follow: 
$n*$row+$i (that $i is the counter of selected row)

Now I want to get the special user rank, how can I do it?
for example user by name='jack' or by id=21
I want a query that exactly get the mentioned user rank.

Comment: We can't even see your database schema; how can we answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the rank in MySQL.  Here is one approach:

```
SELECT id, name, @rn := @rn+1 as `rank`
from `users` cross join (select @rn := 0) const
ORDER BY points desc
```

Comment: thats great, but I want a query that return One value for id=40 for example instead of return whole users table. I think that way can have better performance. @Gordon Linoff